# Does the Minereum Automatic Token Creation Service Work?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, mining, contract-design, tokens

I recently stumbled upon Minereum which they say is the first self mining smart contract token.

They released a service that supposedly allows anyone to create a Ethereum Token with just a Minereum transaction, their ANN thread: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1867535.0

Here is the release post of the Token Service:

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1867535.msg19583893#msg19583893

Is this service legit?

I don't have coding experience but if this works and is not a scam I will definitely create one too!

Answer (score 1):

While it works, their "self mining" is nothing more than a gimmicky marketing stunt. No smart contract can "self do anything" they all (at least at the time this comment is being made) require being poked by someone.

So to answer your question, ues Minereum "works" but there are infinitely better products out there that don't rely on marketing fluff or gimmicks.

Answer (score 0):

The service works, I created a Token without problems.

Very good